# How does the review monitoring product from Birdeye cache Google reviews

Tags: google-places-api

The [review monitoring product](https://birdeye.com/brand-monitoring/) from Birdeye.com allows users to filter reviews by a time period, such as the past 7 days (30 days, 2 months, 3 months, 6 months, all time). Are they storing the reviews in their database? 
I know Google Place API doesn't allow us to cache or store any content except for place ids.

Answer (score 0):

They are storing reviews in their database but they are not using google place api to collect reviews. Instead, they are using [google my business api](https://developers.google.com/my-business/) to store reviews for their clients.